# where can I find some examples of view Switching for uwp program in c++/winrt

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

how do I switch from one view to another?

e..g one view is IFrameworkView for direct draw, the other one is ApplicationT.

I wan to load my app with the UI XAML app and then press something to switch to an instance of the IFrameworkView for animation rendering. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

> where can I find some examples of view Switching for uwp program in c++/winrt

You may need to create multiply views and switch between them by [`ApplicationViewSwitcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewSwitcher) class. Details about this you can reference [Show multiple views for an app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/show-multiple-views).

But according to your description, what you want to do is more like projecting your app. Fortunately, there is a C++ official sample [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Projection/cpp) for projection you can test it to see if it is what you want.